# Google Analytics Api - Get Keywords position

Tags: api, google-analytics, keyword

Im trying to get keywords from my own google analytics account by api.

Im using below code to get a result from Google Analytics Api

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $profileId,
  '30daysAgo',
  'today',
  'ga:sessions',
  array(
    'dimensions'  => 'ga:keyword',
    'sort'        => 'ga:keyword',
    'max-results' => 10
  ));

It returns below result, but it is only 4 keywords i want all keywords, how can i do that?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => (not provided)
        [1] => 264
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => (not set)
        [1] => 1417
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => keyword
        [1] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => keyword
        [1] => 2
    )
```

Comment: Do you actually have more than 4 keywords (given that these days keywords for organic search are "(not provided)" as in the first entry of you result) ?

Comment: Hi Eike, If i look at my google analytics, i have over 1000's of querys. i would like to get them all from google analytics API is that possible.?